# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects 1

Tags: python, while-loop, typeerror

Assume s is a string of lower case characters.
Write a program that prints the number of times the string 'bob' occurs in s. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then program should print
Number of times bob occurs is: 2

I wrote this program below.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
count = 0
if(s.find("b")):
    p = s.index('b')
    while p+2 <= len(s):
        if(s[p+1] == 'o' and s[p+2] == 'b'):
            count = count+1
            p = s[p+2]
        else:
            p = s[p+1]
print (count)
```

But it shows errors on while loop. But if I don't use while loop, it runs without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
count = 0
if(s.find("b")):
    p = s.index('b')
    while p+2 <= len(s):
        if(s[p+1] == 'o' and s[p+2] == 'b'):
            count = count+1
            p = p+2
        else:
            p = p+1
print (count)
```

You have an error on incrementing p.

I would suggest using regexp for this though.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
count = 0
result = ''
ind = 0
for i in range(3,len(s),3):
    result += s[ind:i]
    if "bob" in result:
        count+=1
    ind = i
    result = s[i-1]
print(count)
```